pl sql return row when dataset contains string from another dataset
I am working with 2 data sets and I want to return results when the column in one of them contains text from the other. All datatypes are NVARCHAR2, Oracle SQL Developer 21.4.1.349, Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0
The House Rules:
I must use CTE's
I must not use Subqueries (Sub selects\Derived queries)
I must not use cursors
So the data looks like this, there are no common columns between datasets A and B:



COLUMN1
COLUMN2




PO4147
VALUE2






COLUMN1
COLUMN2




PO4147PO4148
VALUE2



I want to return the row in DATA_SET_B when DATA_SET_B.COLUMN1 contains somewhere in it the value in DATA_SET_A.COLUMN1
I have been trying all morning, with the latest attempt looking like this and not working:
with DATA_SET_A as (select COLUMN1, COLUMN2
                     from TABLE1)
    ,DATA_SET_B as (select COLUMN1, COLUMN2
                     from TABLE2)


select b.COLUMN1, b.COLUMN2
from  DATA_SET_A a, DATA_SET_B b
where 1=1
  and b.COLUMN1 like '%' || a.COLUMN1 || '%'


Shouldn't the last line be the other way around - b.COLUMN1 like '%' || a.COLUMN1 || '%' ? (Also do your house rules prevent you using ANSI join syntax? And why are you using CTEs here at all rather than just joining the tables?)

typo in question corrected. ANSI allowed. The house rules are the house rules.

Your code works fiddle. But it could be simpler SELECT b.COLUMN1, b.COLUMN2 FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.COLUMN1 LIKE '%' || a.COLUMN1 || '%'; (which has no sub-queries or cursors).

works thanks, also I had the columns the other way around in the live query aswell which confused things.

Everything works, just change in the condition "where"
a.COLUMN1 like '%' || b.COLUMN1 || '%' on b.COLUMN1 like '%' || a.COLUMN1 || '%'
with DATA_SET_A as (select 'PO4147' COLUMN1, 'val2' COLUMN2
                     from dual)
    ,DATA_SET_B as (select 'PO4147PO4148' COLUMN1, 'val2' COLUMN2
                     from dual)


select b.COLUMN1, b.COLUMN2
from  DATA_SET_A a, DATA_SET_B b
where 1=1
  and b.COLUMN1 like '%' || a.COLUMN1 || '%'

